# Ways to deal with es6 module paths and dependencies

Tags: javascript, es6-modules

What are some ways to deal with es6 modules and dependencies?

In particular I have 1 library i'd like to split into 3 modules. Let's call the library "salad" and uses "utensils" and "ingredients". Right now all 3 parts are part of the same library but I'd like to separate them. "utensils" is useful on its own. "ingredients" should be separate if only because it only includes a few common ingredients. It's perfectly valid to use the "salad" library with your own ingredients.

So, in actually trying to do it I run into issues. Utensils is easy, it has no dependencies

```
//  utensils.js
export { fork, knive, spoon, }
```

salad is also easy, it has no dependences

```
// salad.js
export { chop, toss, dice }
```

but ingredients is where the issues show up

```
// ingredients.js
import { knive } from './utensils.js';  // what path here?
import { chop, dice } from './salad.js';     // what path here?

export { choppedLettuce, dicedTomates } // they use 'chop' and 'dice'
```

If everything is local and in my own project this is not so difficult but I want all 3 projects to be publically available and easily usable.

Use cases include

- using with rollup/webpack
- using live in the browser no build
- using via npm with rollup/webpack
- using in node no build

If I use npm based paths (assuming the packages are named 'utentils' and 'salad'

```
import { knive } from 'utensils';  
import { chop, dice } from 'salad';
```

Then ingredients.js is no longer usable without npm and pacakge.json. No more live import in a browser

If I use local paths

```
import { knive } from './utensils.js';  
import { chop, dice } from './salad.js';
```

It only works if I put all the files in the same folder which kind of defeats the purpose of separating them.

In other languages I'd probably end up adding include paths or some other way for ingredients.js be able to reference paths that are resolved later. I think webpack has some @symbol solution but that's webpack specific.

One other solution which seemed less than desirable was to have a setup function in ingredients.js to pass in the dependencies

```
// ingredients.js
export { setup, choppedLettuce, dicedTomates }
```

which would then be used like

```
import { knive } from './utensils.js'; 
import { chop, dice } from './salad.js'; 
import { setup, choppedLettuce, dicedTomates } from 'ingredients.js';

// pass in the deps so no paths needs to be ingredients.js
setup({knive, chop, dice});
```

That seems like a non-scalable solution.

It could also be that every function in ingredients takes needs to be passed salad and utensils. That seems yuck.

Is there a solution? Do I just need to have multiple versions of the libraries, some for npm based inclusion, others for live inclusion? Am I overlooking some obvious solution?

Comment: It's a nice use of metaphors, but I think the metaphor is a little bit off. An alternative might be that of a `chef` and a `knife`. Where the `knife` can `chop()`, `slice()`, and `dice()`. The `chef` can use any `knife` as long as it supports these methods. If you are okay with introducing a `kitchen`, you could leave it up to the developer to stock the `kitchen` with their choice of `knife`. The `chef` would no longer just have a `knife`, instead, the `chef` would have to go to the `kitchen` to get a `knife`.

Comment: maybe I chose bad example names but you can come up with dependencies that demo the issue. A physics library depends on a collison library. Both depend on math library. So what should the paths be on the import statements in the physics library?

Comment: apparently this is a known issue. .[one proposed solution: import maps](https://github.com/WICG/import-maps)

Comment: IMO, the physics library and the collision library should manage their own math dependencies. They could very well end up being the same library, but ultimately it shouldn't matter if they are the same or if they are different as long as they produce the correct behaviour.

Comment: That's arguably the worst of all worlds. You'd get bloated code (multiple math libraries) and slow code (having to convert from one math library to the other). Physics requires collision therefore it has to interface with the collision library. If it uses it's own math library that just worse. But your comments are entirely irrelevant to the question